# in iterator i have expected primary-expression before 'int'

Tags: c++11, compiler-errors

```
List<int> list;
// Insert elements to the beginning of the list:
ASSERT_NO_THROW(list.insert(1, list.begin())); // 1
ASSERT_NO_THROW(list.insert(2, list.begin())); // 2 1
// Insert elements to the end of the list:
ASSERT_NO_THROW(list.insert(3, list.end())); // 2 1 3
ASSERT_NO_THROW(list.insert(4, list.end())); // 2 1 3 4
// Can't dereference an iterator pointing to the end of the list
ASSERT_THROW(ListExceptions::ElementNotFound, *list.end());
Iterator<int> iterator = list.find(IntEquals(1));
```

---

in line:
Iterator iterator = list.find(IntEquals(1));
i get the error : expected primary-expression before 'int'

Comment: [This documentation](http://crpcut.sourceforge.net/1.0.3/ASSERT_THROW.html) seems to answer to the question.

Comment: Use `auto` (i.e., `auto iterator = list.find(IntEquals(1));`)

Comment: It appears that `Iterator` is not defined as a template. If `List` is anything like `std::list`, try `List<int>::Iterator`. If `List` is not like `std::list`, then show its definition and that of `Iterator`; in other words, [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or it didn't happen.